# Python convert int to hex string with even number of characters

Tags: python, hex, data-conversion

I want to convert an arbitrary integer into a hex string with an even number of hex characters. i.e. each consecutive pair of characters in the string represent a byte of the integer (in big-endian).

So the hex string should start with a zero character iff needed in order to make an even number of characters.

Since the integer is arbitrary, I do not know the length of the hex string in advance. There are lots of other questions about how to add leading zeros, but they all assume I know the length of the desired hex string. I did not find a duplicate of this specific question anywhere.

I'm happy to use Python 3.8.

I've tried the following:

```
i = 1000  # required output is '03e8'. i could be much larger or smaller

f"{i:02x}"             # '3e8'
f"{i:0>2x}"            # '3e8'
f"{i:x}".zfill(2)      # '3e8' 
"0" + f"{i:x}" if len(f"{i:x}") % 2 else f"{i:x}"  # '03e8' as required, but really?!
```

Isn't there a concise way to do this using format specifiers?

Comment: `hex(i)='0x3e8'` use `hex()`.

Comment: @Ch3steR this is not the correct answer. This does not add a leading zero, it just adds the prefix '0x'. It does not give `'0x03e8'`, so there are still only 3 hex characters, not 4

Comment: add input and expected outputs.For  `hex(150000)= '0x249f0'` what should be the expected output,  `hex(20)='0x14'` what is expected ouput?

Comment: As I said in the question, I want an even number of hex characters. Using the example from the question, the expected conversion of integer 1000 is `'03e8'`. If you insist on prefixing `'0x'` I can live with that too, so `'0x03e8'` is acceptable. However, `hex()` does not give the required output for input 1000.

Comment: Check the answer I posted.

Comment: "I do not know the length of the hex string in advance": the number of digits in base-16 is `(1+math.floor(math.log(val)/math.log(16)))`. You don't want odd numbers so either round this up to the next even number, or use `(2+2*math.floor(math.log(val)/math.log(256)))`... Better just use `hex` and test the length, though.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware that I can write code to do this. My question was "Isn't there a concise way to do this using format specifiers?"

Comment: @eddydee123 Have you checked my answer?

Comment: @Ch3steR yes, but as I said, I'm aware that I can write code to do this. My question was "Isn't there a concise way to do this using format specifiers?"

Answer (score 1):

you could do if you wish to keep the 0x at the beginning of the string:

```
def even_hex(my_int):
str = hex(my_int)
if len(str) % 2 == 1:
    str = str.replace('0x', '0x0')
return str
```

or

```
def even_hex_without_ox(my_int):
str = hex(str)
if len(str) % 2 == 1:
    str = str.replace('0x', '0')
else:
    str = str.replace('0x', '')
return str
```

if you wish to remove it.